# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal', but requires a model 'Namepace.Models.User'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult UserProfileSetting(int id)
{
    int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
    if (UserID > 0)
    {
        var User = DB.Users.Where(x => x.UserID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        return PartialView("_Error404");
    }
    return View(User);
}

public partial class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsEmailVerified { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> ActivationCode { get; set; }
    public string ResetPasswordCode { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

<li class="dropdown" style="margin-top:2px">

    <a href="/Dashboard/UserProfileSetting/14"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Setting</a></li>

</li>
```

Getting first time this error and getting error when checking the session value null or not . Without IF statement it is running right. Where i am doing mistake.

Comment: does this compiles? and show the view code

Comment: @EhsanSajjad not understand what you saying ?

Comment: show view and model too, the controller code does it builds without errors?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad yeah it builds without error and code works perfectly whithout IF statement i used breakpoint in both ways without IF and with statement . But got error while checking session value.

Comment: that does not help in solving your issue unless you show the model and view as well

Comment: @EhsanSajjad ok fine i am updating my question.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad please check edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is the scoping of your "User" variable in your if statement.

```
public ActionResult UserProfileSetting(int id)
{
    int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
    if (UserID > 0)
    {
        var User = DB.Users.Where(x => x.UserID == id).FirstOrDefault(); 
       //this is not the same object that are returning below. This is an instance of your User class. It is only available in this if statement.
    }
    else
    {
        return PartialView("_Error404");
    }
    return View(User); //This is not the same object as the "User" variable above. This is a System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal
}
```

Try changing your code to this and it should fix that error:

```
public ActionResult UserProfileSetting(int id)
{
    int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
    User user = null;
    if (UserID > 0)
    {
        user = DB.Users.Where(x => x.UserID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        return PartialView("_Error404");
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it helped but one thing to know that how variable type is change in IF statement ?

Comment: @AsifShakir It's not changed. User (with a capital U) will get you the current logged in windows user - see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal?view=netframework-4.7.2). If you want to see what I mean, change your if statement to "var user = DB.Users.Where(x => x.UserID == id).FirstOrDefault();". Your code will still compile, because "User" in your return statement is not the same object. Make sense?

Comment: yeah i see. Thanks Again !